# VBA Why is my loop stuck on the first item, after I ensure it doesn't meet criteria

Tags: excel, vba, loops, logic

I am currently using a for loop that goes through two ranges of data - if it sees that a cell in the first row has the word "Rejected" and that the second row is empty it is meant to fill that cell with pending, then spawn an email before exiting the sub.

Once you start the loop again it is is meant to find the next row that meets these arguments. However it only goes to the first one again.

I tried to negate this by making sure it fills that cell with 'pending' - meaning it is no longer empty, and yet it still only goes to there.

Here's the code:

```
Dim i As Long 'Defining i, which will be used to loop through the ranges.

For i = 6 To 50000 'Setting the ranges -
    If Range("M" & i) = "Rejected" And Range("N" & i) = "" Then 'Searches through the ranges first job that the partner has rejected - and then checks as to whether the partner has issued their assessment.
        Range("O" & i) = "'Pending" 'Changes the first one that has been  to 'Pending' so it won't be picked up the next time the code is run.
        GoTo Email
    End If
Next
```

I'm not really sure how else to go about it. I need the sub to stop once it's done an email else it could loop and create hundreds at a time which not only would overload the system, by would inundate my inbox.

Ps, not sure why my code is formatting weirdly - sorry

Comment: Your `If` is concerned with `"M" & i` and `"N" & i`. You do not change them, so they stay the same. You only change `"O" & i` which your `If` does not care about.

Answer (score -1):

The thing is that you are using a `GoTo` and does what is supposed to do, Go to... your Mail label. Once there it will continue the code down, never will go up, is like skipping the loop. Instead you can put your email code into another procedure and call it when necessary, that way the loop will continue:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test()

    Dim C As Range 'this will loop through the range
    Dim LastRow As Long 'this will find the last row

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MySheetName") 'change MySheetName
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row 'last row with data on column M
        For Each C In .Range("M6:M" & LastRow) 'loop through M6 to M & last row
            If C = "Rejected" And .Cells(C.Row, "N") = vbNullString And Not .Cells(C.Row, "O") = "'Pending" Then 'vbnullstring has better performance than ""
                .Cells(C.Row, "O") = "'Pending"
                Mail C.Row
            End If
        Next C
    End With

End Sub
Sub Mail(MailRow As Long)

    'Code doing your mail

End Sub
```

Comment: The OP says, "I need the sub to stop once it's done an email". Their point is that they will run the entire loop again at some point later, and when it happens, they want the next record to be processed.

Comment: Now your code has the same problem as the original code (processing the same record when the loop is restarted).

Comment: Cheers @GSerg, That's what I was worried about looking above :)

Comment: @GSerg what? everytime C is changing from M6 to Mx... and changing the row accordingly... what is not changing here?

Comment: Every time C is changing the `M6` to `Mx`. At some point it finds an `My` and exits the loop. Then you restart the loop, it starts changing from `M6` to `Mx`, and it's going to find the same `My` again instead of remembering to skip it and look for another matching record. That was the original problem.

Comment: Ok now I got it, sorry. @MimiBeard what about adding another criteria, `And Not OX = "Pending"`That would help? Should it always skip the ones with Pending on column O?

Comment: @Damian, yeah it should always be skipping them, that's why filled them with pending in the first place. How would I add the other criteria then?

Comment: There goes my edit @MimiBeard. Thought, why are you checking column Nand assigning the pending on column O? Wouldn't it be better assign the pending on column N?

Comment: Oh, yeah I forgot to update that when I changed rows!  Thank you! That letter change alone fixes it!

Comment: Glad I could finally help. Sorry for not reading all the post at once.